# Proving collinear points - geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles

Straight line $p$ contains the orthocenter $H$ of an acute triangle $ABC$, where $p$ intersects sides $AB$ and $AC$ with $p$ intersecting $AC$ in the point $P$. Straight line $q$ also contains $H$, is perpendicular to $p$ and intersects $AB$ and $BC$ with $q$ intersecting BC in the point $Q$. Straight line containing $A$, parallel to $q$ and a straight line containing $B$, parallel to $p$ intersect in the point $R$. Prove that $P,Q$ and $R$ are collinear.

A question I came across in a practice book, I am not sure even where to start... I'm allowed to use trigonometry, similar triangles, point-line-plane.

[image]

Comment: Please, provide a figure.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have added one.

Comment: @Vedast: Even if you aren't sure where to start, you can provide context. Eg, you mention that this came from a "practice book"; say something about the level of the book, the topic(s) covered in the chapter, etc. The more you can tell us what you know (or "should" know) about the problem, the better someone's chances of helping you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (Also, posting a problem w/no evidence of personal effort can *look* like you're just trying to get someone to do your homework for you.)

Comment: HR seems to be perpendicular to PQ. May be prove similarity of triangles?

Comment: @Moti Nop, in general, $HR$ is not perpendicular to $PQ$. However, similar triangles seems to be the best tool needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B'$ be a point on $AC$ such that $\angle AB'B = 90°$. Denote the intersection point of $AR$ and $BB'$ by $B''$.

Case 1: When $B''$ is out of $\overline {BH}$

[image]

Joint $AH$, $B'N$ and $PB''$. Let $M$ be the intersection point of $BR$ and $QH$, and $N$ be the intersection point of $AR$ and $HP$.
Since $\triangle BMH$ ~ $\triangle HNB''$, $BM \times NB'' = MH \times HN$.
Also, $\angle AB'H = \angle ANH = 90°$ implies $B'B''NP$ and $AHNB'$ are cyclic quadrilateral.
$\Rightarrow \angle B''PN = \angle HB'N = \angle HAN = 90° - \angle AHN$
$\Rightarrow B''P \perp AH$, $B''P$//$BC$
$\Rightarrow \triangle B''PN$ ~ $\triangle QBM$
$\Rightarrow PN\times MQ = BM \times NB'' = MH \times HN = RN \times MR$
$\Rightarrow \triangle NPR$ ~ $\triangle MRQ$
$\Rightarrow \angle QRM = \angle RPN$
$\Rightarrow P$, $Q$ and $R$ are collinear

Case 2: When $B''$ lies on $\overline {BH}$
A → B and B → A
As same as Case 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Collinearity]

We draw the two altitudes $AX$ and $BY$ of the given scalene acute triangle $ABC$. For brevity, let $HP$ and $HQ$ equal $d$ and $e$ respectively. We also assume that $\measuredangle BCA=\omega$ and $\measuredangle HPA=\phi$.

We start our proof by doing some angle chasing in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$. In the right angle triangle $AMP$,
$$\measuredangle PAM=90^o-\measuredangle MPA=90^o-\phi.$$

In a similar vein, by considering the right angle triangle $PYH$, we can state that,
$$\measuredangle YHP=90^o-\measuredangle HPY=90^o-\phi.$$

The line $HP$ is parallel to the line $BN$ and the altitude $BY$ is their transversal. Therefore, the two corresponding angles $\measuredangle YHP$ and $\measuredangle HBN$ are equal, i.e.
$$\measuredangle HBN=90^o-\phi.$$

As a consequence, in the right angle triangle $BNH$,
$$\measuredangle NHB=90^o-\measuredangle HBN=\phi. \tag{1}$$

Finally, consider the two right angle triangles $AXC$ and $CYB$, which share $\measuredangle BCA$. Since, we have assumed $\measuredangle BCA=\omega$,
$$\measuredangle CAX=\measuredangle YBC=90^o-\measuredangle BCA =90^o-\omega. \tag{2}$$

Now we have all the angles we need to proceed with the proof. First, consider the two triangles $AHP$ and $BQH$. They are similar triangles because of (1) and (2). Therefore, we shall write,
$$\frac{AP}{BH}=\frac{HP}{HQ}=\frac{d}{e}. \tag{3}$$

Let us pay our attention to the two right angle triangles $AMP$ and $BNH$. Because of (1), these two triangles are also similar. Hence, with the help of (3), we can state the following equation.
$$\frac{MP}{NH}=\frac{AP}{BH}=\frac{d}{e}. \tag{4}$$

Consider the right angle triangle $PMR$, where we denote $\measuredangle RPM$ as $\theta$, which then can be express as,
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{MR}{PM}\right).$$

Since $HNRM$ is a rectangle, we have $MR=NH$. Therefore, using (4) we can write,
$$\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{NH}{PM}\right)= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{e}{d}\right). \tag{5}$$

Now, visualize what happens if we join $P$ and $Q$. The triangle $PHQ$ becomes a right angle triangle. Therefore, using what we have assumed at the beginning of our proof $\left(\mathrm{i.e.}\space HP=d\space\space \mathrm{and}\space\space HQ=e \right)$, we can express $\measuredangle QPH$ as,
$$\measuredangle QPH = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{HQ}{HP}\right)= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{e}{d}\right) ,$$
which, according to (5), is equal to $\theta$. Therefore, $\measuredangle QPH = \measuredangle RPM$, which implies that the point $R$ lies on the line $PQ$.